# CurrentCellChanged on cell changed only

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm currently writing a `WPF` application where my `DataGrid` is bound to a collection of objects. I need an event that triggers when the user changes cells. This works fine when I have more than 1 row/object in my collection.

Here is my scenario:

```
COLUMN 1   |   COLUMN 2   |   COLUMN 3   |   COLUMN 4
test       |   test 1     |   test       |   1000
```

If I type in a value in column 4, I want to be able to trigger an event and determine that the user typed in a value for column 4 and make other calls/calculations. With the Microsoft DataGrid in 3.5, this is difficult when handling only 1 row.

Here is my code that I have:

```
private void PART_DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn currentColumn = (sender as Presentation.DataGrid).CurrentColumn;

            if (currentColumn == null || currentColumn.DisplayIndex != 3 || !m_isEditedFinished)
                return;

            if (m_vm.MYCommand.CanExecute(null))
            {
                if (CurrentRow != null)
                {
                    if (m_isEditedFinished)
                    {
                        m_vm.MYCommand.Execute(new EnterUserCountCommandParameters()
                        {
                            ViewModel = m_vm,
                            Item = CurrentRow
                        });

                        m_isEditedFinished = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    private Boolean m_isEditedFinished = false;

    private void OnCellEditEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentRow = e.Row.Item;
        m_isEditedFinished = true;
    }
```

Any ideas of what else I can do?

Comment: Because This event gets triggered whenever a cell is entered/left. It is hard to determine which is which. I'm just wondering if there is a better way to determine when exactly a focus has entered/left a cell and where it has gone.

Answer (score 0):

In you ViewModel you're obviously exposing some `List<SomeItem>` because you're using it to set the ItemSource in the datagrid.

- In `SomeItem` implement INotifyPropertyCahnged
- In `ViewModel` listen/respond to `SomeItem`'s property changed and do necessary work

Something like this:

```
//when populating your List, before adding each SomeItem subscribe to IPropertyChanged 
var newItem = new SomeItem();//..some properties I assume
 newItem.PropertyChanged += (s,e) =>
 {
     switch(e.PropertyName)
     {
          case "Column#4Property" :
         //Do work that responds to that property changed
         break;
  }
  _myList.Add(newItem);
```